# Position of lines in TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I've made a couple tessellations in TiKz, but I found that when using the \foreach command, starting positions of the lines are incorrect. I'm not sure why this is.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \y [count=\j, evaluate=\j as \y using 2*sqrt(2)*\j]  in {-8,0,8}{
        \foreach \x in {-8,-4,...,8}
        {
            \draw[line width=1.8pt][-] ($({\x},{\y})$) -- ($({\x+2},{\y+ 2*sqrt(2)})$);
        }
    }
    \foreach \z [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \z using 2*sqrt(2)*\i]  in {-4,4}{
    \foreach \r in {-8,-4,...,8}
    {
    \draw[line width=1.8pt][-] ($({\r},{\z})$) -- ($({\r},{\z+ sqrt(2)})$);
}
}
```

Produces

[image]

I don't understand why the line with initial y coordinate 2*sqrt(2)*(-8) starts at the same place as the line with initial y coordinate 2*sqrt(2)*(-4), for example.

As you can see, I tried to separate the code into two parts with different labels, in case some kind of dependence was occurring, but that did not help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your

```tex
\foreach \y [count=\j, evaluate=\j as \y using 2*sqrt(2)*\j]  in {-8,0,8}
```

the loop variable `\j` will be `1, 2, 3`, hence `\y = 2*sqrt(2)*\j` will be irrelevant with the list `-8,0,8`.

What you need is

```
\foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \y using 2*sqrt(2)*\j]  in {-8,0,8}
```

This time `\j` will be `-8,0,8`, hence `\y` will be the desired values.

Also, `($({\x},{\y})$) -- ($({\x+2},{\y+ 2*sqrt(2)})$)` can be simplified to `(\x,\y) -- (\x+2,{\y+2*sqrt(2)})`.

Comment: Thank you, this clears up my misunderstanding. Also for the tip about the braces. I have been using scraps of code, not always understanding how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You Have to add the last tree lines of my code and change, in your code {-4,4 in {-4,0,4}

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{float,graphicx,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \foreach \y [count=\j, evaluate=\j as \y using 2*sqrt(2)*\j]  in {-8,0,8}{
                    \foreach \x in {-8,-4,...,8}
                    {
                        \draw[line width=1.8pt][-] ($({\x},{\y})$) -- ($({\x+2},{\y+ 2*sqrt(2)})$);
                    }
                }
                \foreach \z [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \z using 2*sqrt(2)*\i]  in {-4,0,4}{
                    \foreach \r in {-8,-4,...,8}
                    {
                        \draw[line width=1.8pt][-] ($({\r},{\z})$) -- ($({\r},{\z+ sqrt(2)})$);
                    }
                }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]